# Vega-Lite (Deneb): Donut Chart - Unable to aggregate text marks against aggregated categories

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, vega-lite, deneb

Any assitance warmly welcomed. I imagine I'm missing something obvious, but very stuck with this one.

Please see images, and links to Vega-Lite editors below:

I have two fields "Medium" (aka Subcategory) and "Medium-Type" (aka Category). I'm able to produce a donut by **subcategory**, with corresponding data labels. However, when aggregating the donut by **Category**, the donut segments behave correctly, but I'm unable to aggregate the text marks in the same way.

**Dataset:**

[image: Dataset]

[EG1: Donut - SubCategory (VL Editor)](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJghgLhIFygG4QDYFcCmBneBtUAshmAJZoC28IAIiQE4YDGUABARCSiADQgCCYRBjpQSWEgDsA5iwDKACwgN4AZgB0AJl5FSFALQAVAJ4AHDFQASSsCwDCAexNGQAX26FiZSnBAAFe1hQwji8AkIiYpIyCkrmcOoALNqe+sZmltZ2js5uHrrefgxYIfyCwqLi0nKKynAArGpJIDpehqZxIFZ0Ng5Oru7NKQUGGCgYiJH2Ejyl4RVR1bHwAGwAnGoAHMn5bek+tFIkMFy5g-lUtpIY5LChZRGV0TVxAAxqAOzbrWkdB0eo-TyXioACUIKR7DMwuVIlUYrUNGoAIxfVLtUHgkiQ04tChUACSEiCdAkGCgUPu8zhz3gSIaTVx5F2vxIh2OrgAum4QAB3EhgKDyKh1F4vGbyDCs+TknwisW8Ezg0jSeCgKCOeB1Xh0KUyl68ABG9ig6u8WpAYwAZnruSgIEZhHhQDc6ABrVUgKDonxKRgzexoYlg3Q4BAgDAADxMdCoAAoJbqWAAqFhvOosACULH6IEkpLowbIodAkejcYTUmlydTahUmez3MCdHsro6BrtjHdvEY9hJwkLaFD5sVYD40jG8DeLwSLlOLvdYa9e09kfJvEtUygshIAC84hp9SAN0SAOqSysykBGlBgGZ0TGDj2lmM+ePnqsptN1DOubkYCQ9sqUgekEEYyqAlokKMt4+NCDwLPC5i8EuHQSPY5CSAC3KCmSsBhpB0FUHBVJPEsyHeiAACOaAQES-yiEIMyBBAnZUGhdA3Cgu7mNyPYoL2HrIOgbYdu6s4uByvD-oBUQgRKMAegRN5EZSsKkco5HLtRtGiDADFISAEBSFIDBSNAHRYHivDMaxPjsZx3E5r2YCOvhUHKbBqmPIsGmehR2l0XpJCMdZvaXi5WCMP+QE5nxAlhmMUjRSBRwTj4jIsLGACkP68Il0UAJrwHoSKHr2UFElQOoXkxRjkNe257vACQinlEAGqMABim6Nfu5q6WM3VEr1qgvNySkwWc3zoppqHoZhXChSIinuZNxFqT5BlGSZGBmUEVCWZQvDOa54DYFFEgxbOx2KowRzOGGQmYJOairNdIATBgPIek2LZxBIaAoCgs5AA)
[image]

---

[EG2: Donut - Category (VL Editor)](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJghgLhIFygG4QDYFcCmBneBtUAshmAJZoC28IAIiQE4YDGUABARCSiADQgCCYRBjpQSWEgDsA5iwDKACwgN4AZgB0AJl5FSFALQAVAJ4AHDFQASSsCwDCAexNGQAX26FiZSnBAAFe1hQwji8AkIiYpIyCkrmcOoALNqe+sZmltZ2js5uHrrefgxYIfyCwqLi0nKKynAArGpJIDpehqZxIFZ0Ng5Oru7NKQUGGCgYiJH2Ejyl4RVR1bHwAGwAnGoAHMn5bek+tFIkMFy5g-lUtpIY5LChZRGV0TVxAAxqAOzbrWkdB0eo-TyXioACUIKR7DMwuVIlUYrUNGoAIxfVLtUHgkiQ04tChUACSEiCdAkGCgUPu8zhz3gSIaTVx5F2vxIh2OrgAum4QFA6BAJFgAGb2OjefAgABW9kkECkUgYUmgcXFjioWDxvEFJFGYCojOZMwgOB8jFQjE5vHl9jQJgARs44Lgzt90VyObwAO4kMBQeRUOovF4zeQYVnyck+ANB3gmcGkaTwUBQVX1Xh0MMRl68W32KDJ7x1XhjQWZ7koCBGYR4UA3OgAa0TPPRPiU5t41uJYN0xtAGAAHiY6FQABQhjMsABULDedRYAEoWP0QJJSXQu2QeyB+4OR2OpOHJ9O1Cp54vuYE6PY6x1beXGA3eIwRav12hjYWQLGwHxpGN4G8XgSFxTlrBsECbPYeX7clNSmKBZBIAAvOINCzEBhSJAB1UN9wjEAcxQXU00xN9G23IcfFHHCDynGc6jnVxuQwCQn3jKRGyCPsI1ALUdSoaEHgWeFzF4KBmxAABHNB+VEGBRCEJdfTJWBwN4wj+MpWEniWUTxKkmT-nkkSQECCB7yoCQRRuFAkPMbknxQEVG2QdAbzvBtgJcd0txY+w2I4kMYEbNTdR8ASqW05RdMg-SiUMkgFN4WV5QwRUgjVDUTJgcyfEs0VUFspcRTAKtVO1dSws0x5FiiiCOli2ToAS4zkoVJUMsoXgsBFPCSqwRhmP8+z7EcijQDGKRBo4o4-x8RkWGHABSBii1SwaAE14D0JE0JFbUiSodNcJmLAjHIAiEOQ+AEgDIsIFtUYADE4MulCP1ksZnqJV7VBebkQr1IYDWijpLPIGUuC6nrgvK0LZhharhJmYrSvAbABokIbuUcMyjgdJBUEwf81FWYDeAmDAPUbC8rziCQ0BQFBgKAA)
[image]

Thanks community!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try and update your transform like:

```
{
"joinaggregate": [{"op": "sum", "field": "Advertising Share", "as": "calc"}],
"groupby": ["Medium-Type"]
}
```

Then replace all "Advertising Share" with calc.
Also remove "aggregate": "sum" from theta since it is already aggregated.

```
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "Medium": "Direct Mail",
        "Advertising Share": 3.2,
        "Medium-Type": "Hard Copy"
      },
      {
        "Medium": "Posters",
        "Advertising Share": 3.4,
        "Medium-Type": "Hard Copy"
      },
      {"Medium": "Press", "Advertising Share": 5.4, "Medium-Type": "Hard Copy"},
      {
        "Medium": "Television",
        "Advertising Share": 69.8,
        "Medium-Type": "Digital"
      },
      {"Medium": "Cinema", "Advertising Share": 0.7, "Medium-Type": "Digital"},
      {"Medium": "Radio", "Advertising Share": 2.1, "Medium-Type": "Radio"},
      {
        "Medium": "Internet",
        "Advertising Share": 15.4,
        "Medium-Type": "Digital"
      }
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {
      "joinaggregate": [
        {"op": "sum", "field": "Advertising Share", "as": "calc"}
      ],
      "groupby": ["Medium-Type"]
    }
  ],
  "width": "500",
  "height": "500",
  "padding": {"top": 5, "right": 0, "bottom": 5, "left": 0},
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "arc",
        "outerRadius": {"expr": "(height * 0.5 ) "},
        "innerRadius": {"expr": "(height * 0.3 ) "},
        "stroke": "black",
        "cornerRadius": 5,
        "padAngle": 0.04
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "fontSize": 20,
        "fontWeight": "bold",
        "radius": {"expr": "(height * 0.55)"}
      },
      "encoding": {
        "text": {"field": "calc", "type": "quantitative"},
        "theta": {"field": "calc", "type": "quantitative"},
        "color": {"value": "black"}
      }
    }
  ],
  "encoding": {
    "theta": {
      "field": "calc",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "stack": "normalize"
    },
    "order": {
      "field": "calc",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "aggregate": "sum",
      "sort": "descending"
    },
    "color": {
      "legend": {
        "title": "Medium (%)",
        "legendY": -10,
        "orient": "right",
        "symbolSize": 450,
        "labelFontSize": 25,
        "titleFontSize": 30
      },
      "field": "Medium-Type",
      "type": "nominal",
      "sort": {"field": "calc", "order": "descending"}
    },
    "opacity": {"value": 0.9}
  },
  "view": {"stroke": null}
}
```

In other words you were very, very close.

Adam

Comment: Thank you immensely Adam @APB-Reports! I realise now that we must aggregate both the arc mark AND the text mark, now that I see it, it makes much more sense. I'm indebted to you. Marked as answered/solved!